# Renaming files with the aid of a text file

Tags: linux, bash, rename, kubuntu

I am trying to rename a load of files but don't know how to incorporate the use of a text file with the new names in it.

I have a number of video files I want to rename, using a new list in a text file. e.g.

```
dfhjkg.avi
wyrtrr.avi
jtylktmn.avi
ertjnn.avi
```

To be renamed by new filenames in another text file:

```
File_01_01.avi
File_01_02.avi
File_01_03.avi
File_01_04.avi
```

I am using Kubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I'm putting this on hold since the question is still not clearly defined. If you do not want to provide a dedicated list of input files to be renamed, and the order of your input files is not implicitly defined either (such as alphanumeric, or by last modified date, etc.), then this problem cannot be solved because there is no relation of *input file name* and *output file name* given.

Answer (score 2):

[Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) comes with a nice feature called [`dired`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html), it lets you to list files in a certain directory, edit them and then commit the changes to disk.

You have to:

1. start Emacs;
2. press `C-x d` to navigate in the desired directory;
3. press `C-x C-q` to enable the editor;
4. edit the file names using all the features you like: find/replace, column mode editing, etc.;
5. when you're done press `C-c C-c` to save your changes.

---

Alternatively you can give [Massren](https://github.com/laurent22/massren) a try (I didn't), it should be a kind of standalone `dired`.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [renameutils](http://www.nongnu.org/renameutils/), specifically the "`qmv`" command that comes in that package, for exactly this kind of thing for years now.

By default "`qmv`" shows each filename twice on each line, and you're only meant to modify the second occurrence of the filename.  This is so you can always see the original filename.  However, that can be troublesome with long filenames which cause line wrapping in the editor, so I have this alias:

```
alias qqmv="qmv -fdo"
```

The "`-f`" option changes the format `qmv` uses in the text files, and the "`do`" is the format specification which basically tells it to only list filenames once.

Comment: The OP already has a text file, I think they're just confused about how to handle shell globs.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have two files, `old.txt` and `new.txt`, each containing a line per file that needs to be renamed. Then you can simply call:

```
paste old.txt new.txt | while IFS=$'\t' read -r old new; do 
  mv -i -- "$old" "$new"
done
```

This will only work if file names don't contain newlines or tabs. So you create a file called `old.txt` with:

```
dfhjkg.avi
wyrtrr.avi
jtylktmn.avi
ertjnn.avi
```

And `new.txt` with:

```
File_01_01.avi
File_01_02.avi
File_01_03.avi
File_01_04.avi
```

Then run the script above. In your case, it'd call:

```
mv -- dfhjkg.avi File_01_01.avi
mv -- wyrtrr.avi File_01_02.avi
mv -- jtylktmn.avi File_01_03.avi
mv -- ertjnn.avi File_01_04.avi
```

… but `mv` will still ask you for confirmation if there are files that would be overwritten. Use `echo mv …` to just print the command instead of executing it.

Comment: I am not altering text files, I am changing the names of .avi video files with the use of new filenames that are in a text file.

Comment: Yeah, so you specify the old filenames in a text file and the new filenames in a text file. How else would you know which file to rename how? Or do you have some kind of context where it's unambiguous and the target filenames are given in the alphabetical order of the input files?

Comment: In Kubuntu , using Dolphin file viewer, you can press F4 and it opens a small terminal window at the bottom. It executes whatever command you type in the directory/folder that you are in.
e.g mv *.avi ~/To_Rename
You don't need to specify where you are moving files from.

Comment: Of course. But that command would move all files to a folder called `~/To_Rename` if it exists. If you only want to specify the target file names of a number of existing files, how are you going to make sure that `dfhjkg.avi` ends up as `File_01_01.avi`, `wyrtrr.avi` as `File_01_02.avi`, etc? You have to *specify* this relation somewhere, hence the need for an input file with a list of file names to rename *from*. Your input AVI files aren't even sorted alphabetically…

Comment: It's <something> like this;
for f in NewFileNames.txt; do mv *.avi f; done
I know the 'do mv *.avi f' bit is wrong, that's where I am stumbling.

Comment: `*.avi` expands to all file names in alphanumeric order. You need to somehow map one old file name to one new file name—there's no way around that. So you're going to have to do it manually, or provide a 1:1 mapping of input and output file names.

Comment: You are obviously unable to answer my question.
I GIVE UP!

Comment: Your question isn't answerable when it's ambiguous. Let's pretend I'm your shell. You say, "rename all files to this list!", and then I'd ask, "Ok, but which file exactly should I rename to `File_01_01.avi`?" — or do you want the shell to rename the files in their current alphanumeric order (e.g. `dfhjkg`, `ertjnn`, …)?  That would be feasible, but that's not what you asked for. The order in your question is different.